# CSS: How to change display grid to flex conditionally with CSS selectors?

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox, css-selectors, css-grid

I have a grid that is populated with elements from a v-for loop in Vue. Also, I have a search bar that reduces grid elements based on the input. If the element count is more than 3 then it looks great, but when I only have left 2 elements it's too spaced out. Therefore, I'd like to change display: grid; to display: flex; if elements in the grid are less than 3.

I've tried with CSS selectors, perhaps I'm doing something wrong since I'm fairly new to programming. I know how to add a dynamic class using javascript, however, I'd like to see if it would be possible with plain CSS.

Tried the following css selector and its variations:

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(290px, 1fr) );
    grid-gap: 3rem;

}

.grid-container:first-child:nth-last-child(n + 2) {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: auto;
    align-content: center;
}
```

Comment: there is no selector for number of childs but we can probably do this differently

Comment: Yes there is a pure css solution but you have to fit it to your own document. Check this link:  https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-logical-styling-based-on-the-number-of-given-elements/

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle, so we can play around with your UI and propose some solutions?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I was trying variations based on the #Example 3: Conditional Carousel, but no success...

Comment: @LajosArpad thanks for the offer! I'm fetching data from APIs, so it might be too tedious to create it on the jsfiddle. I'll stick to javascript solution unless some better CSS solution comes up.

Comment: @Inga you can hard-code some example data into your example to simulate API call and this way you can avoid sharing sensitive information.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (without JavaScript) select a parent element based on the number of children it has (with the exception of whether or not that element has 0 (`:empty`) or more (`:not(:empty)` children).

You can, however, select all the children based on the number of siblings they have. This means that you cannot change from `grid` to `flex`, but you could use `display: flex` all the time and then change how the elements flow in the flexbox (ie by modifying their `align-self`, `justify-self`, or `flex-*` properties). I can't give a specific example because I can't see your layout, but I can give a general demo of how it works below.

Here's the breakdown of the selector:

```css
    .container > :first-child:nth-last-child(n + 3),
    .container > :first-child:nth-last-child(n + 3) ~ *
```

- `.container` Select all with the "container" class.
- `>` Select direct children (ie, not children of children) of the container.
- `:first-child` Filter the direct children so you just have the first child.
- `:nth-last-child(n + 3)` Filter the first child so it's only selected if it is three or more elements from the end of its container. This will give 0 elements if the child is less than three elements from the end of its container. In other words it only keeps the selection if the first child has 2 or more siblings following it.
- `~ *` Select all siblings that follow the selected element.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelector("#clickTarget").addEventListener("click", () => {
    let target = document.querySelector(".container > div:last-child");
    target.parentNode.removeChild(target);
  });
});
```

```css
/* 0 or more elements */
.container > .child {
  background-color: blue;
}

/* 3 or more elements */
.container > .child:first-child:nth-last-child(n + 3),
.container > .child:first-child:nth-last-child(n + 3) ~ * {
  background-color: green;
}

/* 6 or more elements (must be after the above rule to override it) */
.container > .child:first-child:nth-last-child(n + 6),
.container > .child:first-child:nth-last-child(n + 6) ~ * {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<button id="clickTarget">
  Pop Last Element
</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
</div>
```